# CakePHP 3 - Passing parameters to application with a single controller where all requests are routed to it

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.x

CakePHP 3.x

In the Routing documentation (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html) it says:

> If you have a single controller in your application and you do not want the controller name to appear in the URL, you can map all URLs to actions in your controller. For example, to map all URLs to actions of the home controller, e.g have URLs like /demo instead of /home/demo, you can do the following:

`$routes->connect('/:action', ['controller' => 'Home']);`

That's fine as it means I can do stuff like this in my `src/Controller/HomeController.php`:

```
public function foo()
{
    // Accessible through URL "/foo"
}

public function bar()
{
    // Accessible through URL "/bar"
}
```

But if I need to pass parameters to a function, e.g.

```
public function baz($a, $b, $c)
{

}
```

It will give me a "Missing Controller" error if I call any of the following URLs:

```
/baz/2
/baz/2/17
/baz/2/17/99
```

It's saying that I need to create "BazController".

All of these, **will work**, because they include the controller name:

```
/home/baz/2
/home/baz/2/17
/home/baz/2/17/99
```

Presumably this is a routing problem?

Interestingly, calling `/baz` **without any parameters** works ok.

Comment: maybe `$routes->connect('/:action/*', ['controller' => 'Home']);`

Comment: Yes, this works @arilia. Thank you. Interestingly it means including the Controller name (e.g. `/home/baz/...`) stops the URL from working, but that's fine because the intention is to get rid of the controller name in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer, as provided in a comment by @arilia is:

```
$routes->connect('/:action/*', ['controller' => 'Home']);
```

The URL's provided in my question will now work as follows. All of these will be mapped to `HomeController.php` and execute the `baz()` function:

```
/baz/2
/baz/2/17
/baz/2/17/99
```

The `*` (at the end of `/:action/*`  in `app/routes.php`) is key to allowing any number of parameters passed in the URL.